# Scraping an href

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if someone could help me scrape an href tag and clean it up. I am trying to scrape the url from the big "Visit Website" button on this page: https://www.goodfirms.co/software/inflow-inventory, and then clean it up a little bit.

Code:

```
url = 'https://www.goodfirms.co/software/inflow-inventory'
page = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
soup = bs(page.content, 'lxml')
try:
    url = soup.find("div", class_="entity-detail-header-visit-website")
except AttributeError:
    url = "Couldn't Find"
Print(url)
```

Output Print:

```
<div class="entity-detail-header-visit-website">
<a class="visit-website-btn" href="https://www.inflowinventory.com/?utm_source=goodfirms&amp;utm_medium=profile" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Visit website</a>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
https://www.inflowinventory.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to get `@href` value

```
url = soup.find("a", class_="visit-website-btn").get('href')
```

Having complete URL you can get base with

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

print(urlsplit(url).netloc)
#  www.inflowinventory.com
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to combine this with the other answer to get what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you what you need:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.goodfirms.co/software/inflow-inventory', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

link = soup.select_one('a.visit-website-btn')
print(link['href'].split('/?utm')[0])
```

Result:

```
https://www.inflowinventory.com
```

Documentation for BeautifulSoup can be found at:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thanks! I was able to combine this with the other answer to get what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`"div", class_="entity-detail-header-visit-website"` detects the same url two times with html content. So `.a.get('href')` with find() method will pull the righ url

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.goodfirms.co/software/inflow-inventory'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

link = soup.find("div", class_="entity-detail-header-visit-website").a.get('href')
print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
https://www.inflowinventory.com/?utm_source=goodfirms&utm_medium=profile
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for a solution according to your code then it is like this.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.goodfirms.co/software/inflow-inventory'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

try:
   url = soup.find("div", class_="entity-detail-header-visit-website")
   print(url.a.get('href'))

except AttributeError:
   url = "Couldn't Find"
   print(url)
```

Result :

```
https://www.inflowinventory.com/?utm_source=goodfirms&utm_medium=profile
```